# How to take /etc/services entry inside a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have an entry in /etc/services file.

`abcde   25354/tcp`

I need to take the port number of the entry `abcde` inside my shell script. How to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '/^imap / { split($2, a, "/"); print a[1]; }' /etc/services
```

You will need to replace imap with abcde, or whatever you are really looking for. You might even need to extend the pattern like `^imap .*tcp`

You may also like

```
getent services imap
```

Which produces:

```
imap                  143/tcp imap2
```

Comment: ya, perfect. I'm looking for any specific command to get the value from etc/services file. Is there any command like `env`

Comment: @Nadaraj: What like `getent services imap`?

Comment: @Nadaraj: You could write your own in C using the `getservbyname` function.

Comment: `getent services abcde` this is what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep`:

```
grep ^abcde /etc/services | grep -o '[0-9]*'
```

The first grep is to get line with `abcde`, the second is to get digits part only.